# Ctrl + J command from VS Code in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I cannot find a way to get the terminal up and down in Visual Studio which can be done in VS Code with `Ctrl + J`. Does anyone have a solution or this?

Comment: Ctrl+J is List Members in Code

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar issue. I by mistake changed the shortcut to something else.

Just click on settings and go to **Keyboard shortcuts**.

Search **View: Toggle Panel** in it and change the key back to whatever you want.